# Cannot get data from class method taken from Firebase

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, database-connection

I have a difficulties to solve my problem. I am connected to Firebase, and trying to set a connection and check if the name is in the database.

```
 class Db {

    connect (path) {
        const db = firebase.firestore();
        const docRef = db.doc(path);
        return docRef;
    }

    exist (name, path) {

        this.connect(path).get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
            console.log(querySnapshot.data().Users);
            const users = querySnapshot.data().Users;
            // return users;
            if (users.indexOf(name) > -1) {
                console.log('yes');
                return true
            } else {
                console.log('no');
                return false
            }
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
        })
    }
}


let databaseurl = '2048/database';
let database = new Db();

console.log(database.exist('kytek', databaseurl));  //undefined
```

from console log I am getting  `undefined`
but console log return an array, I am not sure why...
part with return before if:

```
console.log(querySnapshot.data().Users);
const users = querySnapshot.data().Users;
return users;
```

and consol.log returns array
but `return` returning `undefined`
any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not getting your true/false values because the `exist()` function you've written is asynchronous, and you aren't returning the interior function. If you want to return data from the interior `this.connect().get()` function, you need to return that outer function... what I mean is:

```
exist (name, path) {

    return this.connect(path).get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
        // etc... rest of function here
```

If that doesn't work for you, you may also have to mark the function as `async` and use `await` to wait to receive the result:

```
async exist (name, path) {

    return this.connect(path).get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
        // etc... rest of function here


let databaseurl = '2048/database';
let database = new Db();

let result = await database.exist('kytek', databaseurl);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Your first solution works, and I'm not getting simple false or true but   `Promise {<pending>}  
__proto__: Promise  
[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"  
[[PromiseValue]]: false`